# Adding a Log entry for an action by a user in a Django App

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to create a log entry for changes made by a user to the database via the views in my django application.

I have enabled the django-admin module and I can retrieve the logs of the changes made using the admin interface like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

recentActions = LogEntry.objects.all()

for each in recentActions:
    print 'Action:', each.action_flag.__str__()
    print 'Message:', each.object_repr
    print 'Table:', ContentType.objects.get(id = each.content_type_id).name
```

I want to create similar log entries for actions done by other users using the views in my django application. How do I do this ?

Comment: does it record actions made on models other than from admin also?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're very close. You just need to create new `LogEntry` objects and save them. `LogEntry` has a shortcut function on `objects` to do this.

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, ADDITION, CHANGE

LogEntry.objects.log_action(
            user_id=request.user.id,
            content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model_object).pk,
            object_id=object.id,
            object_repr=unicode(object.title),
            action_flag=ADDITION if create else CHANGE)
```

Comment: For those wondering, available `action_flag` options are `ADDITION`, `CHANGE`, and `DELETION`. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects).

Comment: The official Django implementation can be found in the `django.contrib.admin.options` [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/). Look for the `ModelAdmin` methods: `log_addition`, `log_change`, and `log_deletion`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to log inside methods od ModelAdmin (and not in views) - you can use built-in methods: `log_addition()`, `log_change()` and `log_deletion()`. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56705189/14429896