# Django - Custom Admin Actions Logging

Tags: python, django

All changes you do in Django Admin is logged in the table django_admin_table and you can also see your most recent changes in "Recent Actions".

But when you write own "Admin Actions" and make changes through them nothing is being logged by default.

Example:

```
def make_checked(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(checked = 1)
make_checked.short_description = 'Mark selected products as checked'
```

My question is now if it's possible to log custom admin actions and if so, how?

Comment: [Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7905106)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at the admin's [`LogEntry`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L23) model and more importantly the [`LogEntryManager`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L16). The model manager provides a `log_action` method which makes it easy to add your own log entries (this is untested but should give you the idea):

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, CHANGE
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def make_checked(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(checked = 1)

    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(queryset.model)
    for obj in queryset:
        LogEntry.objects.log_action(
            user_id=request.user.id, 
            content_type_id=ct.pk,
            object_id=obj.pk,
            object_repr=obj.description,
            action_flag=CHANGE,
            change_message="You have ...") 
make_checked.short_description = 'Mark selected products as checked'
```

You can see some examples of [logging being used in the normal django admin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L804). If you only wanted to add a single `LogEntry` for the entire queryset, you could do it manually (as the `log_entry` above expects a certain set of arguments tailored to logging individual objects):

```
l = LogEntry(user_id=request.user.id, actions_flag=CHANGE, change_message="...")
l.save()
```

Answer (score 13):

There's actually now a much easier way to do this than the accepted answer, provided you have a `ModelAdmin` available, which you do in the case of a custom action.

The `ModelAdmin` class is not well documented, but it actually [provides these methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin) as shortcuts:

```python
def log_addition(self, request, object, message):
    """
    Log that an object has been successfully added.

    The default implementation creates an admin LogEntry object.
    """

def log_change(self, request, object, message):
    """
    Log that an object has been successfully changed.

    The default implementation creates an admin LogEntry object.
    """

def log_deletion(self, request, object, object_repr):
    """
    Log that an object will be deleted. Note that this method must be
    called before the deletion.

    The default implementation creates an admin LogEntry object.
    """
```

These are easy enough to use. To continue with the example in the question:

```python
def make_checked(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(checked = 1)
    for obj in queryset:
        modeladmin.log_change(request, obj, 'Marked checked: ' + str(obj))
make_checked.short_description = 'Mark selected products as checked'
```

Comment: ModelAdmin needs to be initialized but log methods can be used as static methods, pass anything as first argument
```
from django.contrib.admin.options import ModelAdmin
ModelAdmin.log_change(None, request, obj, message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! Worked perfect after some minor changes:

```
def make_checked(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(checked = 1)

    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(queryset.model) # for_model --> get_for_model
    for obj in queryset:
        LogEntry.objects.log_action( # log_entry --> log_action
            user_id = request.user.id,
            content_type_id = ct.pk,
            object_id = obj.pk,
            object_repr = obj.title,
            action_flag = CHANGE, # actions_flag --> action_flag
            change_message = 'Changed checked.')
make_checked.short_description = 'Mark selected products as checked'
```

Comment: Oops. That was sloppy. I've updated my post anyway to be clear. Make sure to accept one of the answers as correct anway